# Replace linear return with cosine return

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

Below you will find the position profile in time for a servo-device I am building.  Currently the motion follows the orange profile moving away from zero to a maximum value and then quickly returning to zero to start the cycle all over again.  At $2$ Hz the period is $0.5$ seconds and the maximum amplitude is $1563$ mm. The linear "return to zero" line (orange) has sharp corners where excessively large accelerations are required to follow the profile.  Instead I'd like to define a portion of a cosine function (shown in blue) running from something less than zero to something beyond $\pi$ as the graphical solution shows in blue.  Clearly the majority of the cosine function will be something like $y = 1563\cdot((\cos(\theta)/2)+0.5)$ for $\theta = 0$ to PI.  But I don't know how to figure out how far to extend the function beyond those endpoints to have it's slope exactly match the slope of the $2$ orange lines shown on the image.  The cosine function including the extensions must also fit in the $0.1483$ seconds window allocated for "return to zero".  I believe the solution can be found by differentiating the position equation and setting it equal to the specified velocities (slopes) but I don't know how to do that.

[image: cosine return proposal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to replace the "linear return" with a function of the form
$$
f(t) = A \cos(Bt + C) + D
$$
for a suitable choice of coefficients $A,B,C$. the conditions that must hold are as follows:

1. The maximum of $f$ is $1563 \implies A + D = 1563$
2. $f'(.2151) = 2228 \implies -AB \sin(.2151\cdot B + C) + D = 2228$
3. At $t = .3634$ the slope is $7897 \implies -AB \sin(.2151\cdot B + C) + D = 7897$

You do not say this explicitly, but it seems that the cosine function is supposed to connect to the data at the start and end points. So, we will have two more equations of the form

4. $f(.2151) = y_1 \implies A \cos(.2151 \cdot B + C) + D = y_1$
5. $f(.3634) = y_2 \implies A \cos(.3634 \cdot B + C) + D = y_2$.

What you're looking for is a solution for $A,B,C,D$ to all $5$ of these equations.
Because there are $5$ equations for only $4$ variables, this is a system of equations that is likely overdetermined; for that reason, you should probably ignore the first equation and solve the rest. I do not believe that this equation is analytically solvable, but it should be possible to obtain a numerical solution with any equation solver (e.g. using SymPy).

*Note:* We might be able to simplify the solution process here by rewriting $f$ as
$$
f(t) = A\cos(Ct) + B\sin(Ct) + D
$$
and then using trigonometric identities to rewrite the function in the desired form.

---

A more standard approach towards the effect that you are trying to achieve is to connect the two data points with a [natural cubic spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)#Algorithm_for_computing_natural_cubic_splines). The computational process would be more straightforward.

In particular, you would be looking to replace the linear return with a function of the form
$$
f(t) = At^3 + Bt^2 + Ct + D.
$$
Equations 2-5 would define a linear system:
$$
f'(.2151) = 2228 \implies (3 \cdot (.2151)^2)A + (2 \cdot .2151)B + C = 2228\\
f'(.3634) = 7897 \implies (3 \cdot (.3634)^2)A + (2 \cdot .3634)B + C = 7897\\
f(.2151) = y_1 \implies (.2151)^3 A + (.2151)^2 B + (.2151) C + D = y_1\\
f(.3634) = y_1 \implies (.3634)^3 A + (.3634)^2 B + (.3634) C + D = y_2.\\
$$
In matrix form, the system of equations is
$$
\pmatrix{3 \cdot (.2151)^2 & 2 \cdot .2151 & 1 & 0\\
3 \cdot (.3634)^2 & 2 \cdot .3634 & 1 & 0\\
(.2151)^3 & (.2151)^2 & .2151 & 1\\
(.3634)^3 & (.3634)^2 & .3634 & 1} \pmatrix{A\\B\\C\\D} = \pmatrix{1563\\2228\\y_1\\y_2}.
$$

Comment: So these 4 equations stem from the requirements that the position and velocity (slope) must be equal at both end points.  Is that correct?

Comment: @skinnedKnuckles Yes, that's correct. $f'(t)$ is the slope of the graph of $f$ at $t$.

Comment: This worked beautifully.  Thanks Ben!

Comment: @skinnedKnuckles Glad to hear it!